# creating an xml from the values in a Dialog in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have to create an xml file based on the value of attributes set by user in dialog of Java Swing.There are five attributes name,age,sex,date of birth and place. when the user clicks on OK button of the Dialog box an xml file should be created in the temp directory of the user.

Kindly help me as I am new to Java Swing

Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Create a GUI with controls to collect the data you specified.  Create a class to generate the XML output.  Call this class.

Answer (score 1):

To build a Swing GUI, you start with a `JFrame`.

Within this `JFrame`, you have a master `JPanel`.

The attributes will each have `JLabel` components and `JTextField` components.  You will use a layout manager to arrange the label and text field components.

You have a `JButton` so that the user can tell your program that she's entered all of the attributes.

You should be able to look up all these Swing components and build a GUI.

Then, as jzd said, you create a class to generate the XML output and call this class from the GUI.